# Blogger comments not showing

Tags: wordpress, weblogic, blogs, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6VJY.png)

//The comments as shown in the red circles are not readable nor it can be shown any where in the post or below the post please help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom Blogger template, make sure, that comments b:includable are missed ([some help](http://geekthis.net/blog/131/structure-of-custom-blogger-themes)).